# Volley inside listfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-volley

So i have this ListFragment and i want to run volley request inside onCreateView. The code is like below

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
    mFeedView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mNewPost = (FloatingActionButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.new_post);

    mNewPost.setColorNormal(getResources().getColor(R.color.post_primary));
    mNewPost.setColorPressed(getResources().getColor(R.color.post_pressed));
    mNewPost.setColorRipple(getResources().getColor(R.color.post_rippled));
    mNewPost.attachToListView(mFeedView);

    mNewPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent newPost = new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity.class);
            newPost.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            getActivity().startActivity(newPost);
        }
    });
    mReminderList = new ArrayList<Reminder>();

    final JsonArrayRequest mRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(getFeedUrl(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                        try {
                            JSONObject mItem = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            Reminder mReminder = new Reminder();
                            mReminder.setFirstname(mItem.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME));
                            mReminder.setLastname(mItem.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
                            mReminder.setTitle(mItem.getString(TAG_TITLE));
                            mReminder.setContent(mItem.getString(TAG_CONTENT));

                            mReminderList.add(mReminder);
                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    NetworkUtils.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(mRequest);

    mFeedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(this.getActivity(), mReminderList);
    setListAdapter(mFeedAdapter);
    return mView;
}
```

The adapter is fine, the JSON response is okay. The problem is mReminderList is not filled with Reminder object. Funny, it only happen when i'm using Volley. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you have parsed the json data.

As per [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()),

> notifyDataSetChanged()
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
        try {
            JSONObject mItem = response.getJSONObject(i);
            Reminder mReminder = new Reminder();
            mReminder.setFirstname(mItem.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME));                                                                 
            mReminder.setLastname(mItem.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
            mReminder.setTitle(mItem.getString(TAG_TITLE));
            mReminder.setContent(mItem.getString(TAG_CONTENT));
            mReminderList.add(mReminder);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();                                
        }
     }
     mFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is asynchronous, so its very probable that the response comes after you already set the adapter to the listview.

Instead of adding objects to the `mReminderList`, instance your `FeedAdapter` before making the request, and add the `Reminder` objects to the `FeedAdapter` instance when you got the response.
And do not forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after adding all `Reminders`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding items into adapter, also move the code where you set the adapter before the call to webservice as adapter will be null when you try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Also it is not a good idea to call a webservice or a long operation even if its async in `onCreateView()` as View's are not initialized until the control returns from it.

Move your volley related code from `onCreateView()` to `onViewCreated()` or `onActivityCreated()`

Only inflate the View in `onCreateView` and do `findViewById` etc using `getView()` in `onViewCreated()` and the set adapter to `ListView`, after that call your webservice.